# Iberia Plus vs. Vueling club, comparison of frequent-flyer programs

Tags: loyalty-programs

As a traveler that is making some flights per year mostly using Vueling.
What is recommended to collect the `Avios` the Iberia Plus FF program or instead the Vueling Club?

1. Any comment or consideration that would be useful in the evaluation?
2. Has someone make an evaluation between the two FF programs?

Comment: Don’t know either programme, but since they both collect Avios, are they actually different?

Comment: @jcaron I would imagine that one may be with more advantages than the other... but I have no idea which one.

Comment: A quick look seems to indicate they are quite different, but comparing FF programs is usually quite difficult as it depends a lot on your travel patterns, what benefits are important for you, if you also use an associated credit card, and if so, what your spending patterns are, etc. This seems to be further complicated by the fact that earning patterns for the same flight depend on whether you buy them through the Iberia or Vueling site… set up an Excel sheet, enter the data for your trips and what you would earn in each case, then compare…